# C - Bytes of strcmp and String comparison from Array

Tags: c, strcmp

Thank you in advance for your answer !
I wrote a programm which seems probably correct in my opinion but an error occurs in the compiler (about the first line with strcmp) :

> "Wrong type: Size of element is 4 bytes, but size of String is 8
>   bytes."

```
    float total_weight_kg(Array weight_array) { // todo: modify header (parameters, parameter types, return type)
float sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < a_length(weight_array); i+=2)
{
    if( strcmp(get(String, weight_array, (i+1) ), "kg") == 0 ){ sum = sum + get (float, weight_array, (i)) ;}
    if( strcmp(get (String, weight_array, (i+1) ), "l") == 0  ){ sum = sum + get (float, weight_array, (i)) ;}
    if( strcmp(get (String, weight_array, (i+1) ), "g") == 0  ){ sum = sum + ( get (float, weight_array, (i) )*1000 ) ;}
    if( strcmp(get (String, weight_array, (i+1) ), "mg") == 0 ){ sum = sum + ( get (float, weight_array, (i) ) * 1000000 ) ;}
    else{printf("Impossible for this case. Unknown unit of measurement.");}
}
return sum;}
```

Comment: What is `Array`? What is `a_length`? What is `get`? What is `string`? And on which line do you get the error? And is it the complete and unedited output from the compiler you're showing? Also, please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What exactly is the question?  Are you asking whether the compiler is wrong to reject the program? Probably it isn't.  Are you asking what the compiler is complaining about?  Surely it gave you a better idea than you've given us.  Are you asking how to fix it?  You haven't given us enough information to tell.

Comment: What is `get (float, weight_array, (i))`? `float` is a type, not a variable, so belongs in the function definition, not passed as an argument. I'll bet `String` is also a (ill-advised) type, not a variable. In which case `get` is being passed different types anyway.

Comment: Is `get` a macro? If so by convention it should be `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

**Floats** are 4-bytes. Guessing by your use of the `get` function(s),

```
get(String, weight_array, (i+1) )
```

the issue is with `weight_array` being an array of floats, but the first parameter is doing some executing with a `String` type.

Hence your error,

> "Wrong type: Size of element is 4 bytes, but size of String is 8 bytes."